# How to remove popup with element id in Chrome devtools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Chrome devtools showing this popup with element xpath near selected element that is highlighted (`div#mainbar`). How to hide that popup and only highlight element?
[image]

Comment: because it obscures view of other elements below that popup. in case of example picture - of the top element. In my case it was bottom element on narrow top panel, so I wasn't seeing whole panel

Comment: it's super annoying when trying to debug something and the popup covers it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In 2020 they've added so much info into that popup - so it has become a real nuisance when inspecting the page.

**Partial solution:**
Hold down `Ctrl` or `CMD` key (depending on you OS) while hovering over elements and the popup will not be displayed.

Credit goes [here](https://opensauce.it/disable-detailed-tooltip-in-inspect-mode/)

Answer (score 0):

As of December 2017, there is no setting for removing that popup. It seems like an uncommon use case, so unfortunately I don't think the team would implement that option.

Comment: Thanks for answer. In my experience chrome team never implements anything which is asked by others and which they think is unnecessary.

Comment: Oh, you are a chrome team member, so I better explain what I meant - there was some issue in chrome bugtracker which was implemented in same way in all other browsers, but Chrome implementation was different but correct based on standard. A lot of people asked to unify it to other browsers, but it never happened and I guess was closed. That bug was 6 years old or so in ~2013. I don't recall which issue that was, but I doubt it was changed since then.

Comment: And I seen other issues like that. No bugs is fixed if chrome devs think this is wrong. Maybe there is some margin on how many people need to vote for change, but that one was huge -  a lot of comments. Well, same as Apple way I guess - we know better what you like.

Comment: Also about uncommon use - I don't see why that popup even can be helpful? You selected that element in Elements panel, you already know which element is that. You can see it's dimensions in same Elements panel. Why show duplicate information in popup? It's either just doesn't help or just irritating and obscures the view. Yeah, it's small one, but still irritating.

Comment: in 2020 it obscures the view HEAVILY